# How to avoid duplicated labels for multi-part features in qgis2web?

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

In QGIS, I have `Label every part of multi-part features` unchecked.

But when I use `qgis2web-> create web map`, I see there are duplicated labels for multi-part features.

My QGIS version is 2.16.3

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no solution for this at the moment. It has been raised as a qgis2web issue:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/237

However, I don't yet know how to solve it.